# I need a library and some tips to process a few DXF files

Tags: c#, python, image-processing, vector-graphics, autocad

I need to help a friend with automating a task and find myself in need of some information. 
Basically there are a bunch of DWG files i need to process and i would rather do it by coding than by hand.

All the files contain are shapes that are to be fed into a kind of plotter but the problem is that the lines come out interrupted at intervals and the plotter can't do it's job.

I need to know if there are any ways to hack the image files to make the lines continuous.

I have experience in Python, C# , C and some knowledge of a sum of other programming languages but i have almost no knowledge at all about image processing. I would really appreciate any help you guys can provide.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is too vague. What is the problem here?

Comment: perhaps you can post some lines with the problem you mention, and how you would like them to be processed.

Comment: What type are the files: DXF (like your title says) or DWG (like your questions states)?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few libraries for reading/writing DXF/DWG files, one of them is [CadLib](http://www.woutware.com/cadlib.html), feel free to try it out. The [Open Design Alliance](http://opendesign.com/) also has libraries (in C++, they also have .NET wrappers).